How do I find the time complexity (Big O) of this
void count_of_nodes(struct node*head) {
    int count = 0;
    if(head==null)
            printf("Linked List is empty");
    struct node*ptr = NULL;
    ptr = head;
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        count++;
        ptr = ptr->link;
    }
    printf("%d", count);
}

I am not familiar with calculating the Big O notation for a C program. Additionally, I am new to Big O notation as I am currently learning it in Java. Please help me understand how to determine the Big O notation for the provided C code, which counts the number of nodes in a linked list. Your guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Is there a specific question or problem that if answered would allow you to do the analysis yourself?

Suppose there are n nodes in the list. Figure out how many steps the routine takes, as a function of n. (Use any reasonable definition of a step, including incrementing an object, performing a comparison, following a link.) Then, what “type” of function is it? To go beyond that, you will need to understand the mathematical definition of O notation.

If you are currently learning it in Java, then you can rewrite this program into Java, and do the analysis on your Java code.

Which tutorial are you following? Which book are you learning from? What have you read about big O notation in that book?

Sidenote: this function is more complex than it needs to be. As the head pointer is passed by value, you don't need ptr and the "empty list" print can come at the end, once the length has been calculated. void count_of_nodes(struct node*head) { int count = 0; while (head) { count++; head = head->link; } if (count == 0) printf("Linked List is empty"); printf("%d", count); }
